# require in the firefox addon debugger

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to require('sdk/request') in the firefox addon debugger, however I keep getting the following error

```
"Module `@test/options` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/@test/options.js"
```

This works fine from my addons main js file, it is only when I try and run it in the console that this happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! We are experiencing the same error. Did you get a fix going?